# Jquery elements only work after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am building  Reacts based application, I have a few jquery elements on the page such a the JqueryUI date picker and bootstraps tooltip.

The problem is these elects do not work until i reload the page.

So its like the jQuery scripts are not be loaded the first time around.

I have looked through the console and cannot see any errors related to jQuery/javascript.

Any help would be much appreciated. here is my index.html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

      <title>ICETEA</title>

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

      <!-- JQuery UI JS - Used for the datepicker -->
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
      <!-- JQuery UI CSS - Theme: Blitzer, used for the datepicker -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      });
    </script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#datepicker" ).change(function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "DD d MM" );
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set the function inside the .ready()

Comment: @Baruch - they are `$(function(){...})` is analogous to `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Comment: You need to load jQuery before all your other scripts (it's after Bootstrap JS right now) before anything. First > `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js`

Answer (score 2):

What's probably happening is that your initial page load attempts to load everything from the network, while the second load retrieves assets from browser cache. You could verify this by using your developer tools to always load without cache; if my hypothesis is correct, then you would see a higher prevalence of your errors, even when you reload the page.

As @vanburen pointed out in their comment, the likely explanation is that you're not ordering your scripts correctly. jQuery should always be loaded first, but right now you've got it after Bootstrap. This is supported by the console error you'll see when you attempt to load the page as-is with your developer tools open:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6

As an additional optimization, you can consider putting your CSS before your synchronous scripts, so the browser can be loading and parsing them while it's simultaneously loading your JavaScript.

Bottom line: Be sure to get familiar with your developer tools. They should always be your first resource when you face an unexpected behavior.